# How do you pass code from one class through a second class and into a third?

Tags: java, swing, class, controller

This is going to be very difficult for a novice like me to explain but I'll give it a try. I've created created this class:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

private JTabbedPane tabPane;
private CustomerPanel customerPanel;
private VehiclePanel vehiclePanel;
private OrderPanel orderPanel;
private Controller controller;

public void setController(Controller controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
}

public MainFrame() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    tabPane = new JTabbedPane();
    customerPanel = new CustomerPanel();
    vehiclePanel = new VehiclePanel();
    orderPanel = new OrderPanel();

    tabPane.add("Kunder", customerPanel);
    tabPane.add("Fordon", vehiclePanel);
    tabPane.add("Order", orderPanel);

    add(tabPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }
}
```

As you can see, it contains a couple of panels. In these panels, to be more exact in the CustomerPanel, you will find a class called CustomerFormPanel. This class works as a form where the user can input information like name, person id etc. It's also connected to the controller which brings the GUI and the rest of the classes together. The vital code here is:

```
[...]
public void setController(Controller controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
}
public void CustomerFormPanel() {
[...]
regBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String cName = nameField.getText();
            String pNumber = pNrField.getText();
            controller.addCustomer(pNumber, cName);
            responseLabel.setText("Status: A Customer has been created!");
        }
    });
}
```

Now to main class. This is the class where I bring it all together and it looks like this:

```
public class CustomerApplication {

MainFrame myFrame;

public CustomerApplication() {
    myFrame = new MainFrame();

    myFrame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(700, 640));
    myFrame.setLocation(150, 150);
    myFrame.setSize(1000, 900);
    myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    myFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    CustomerApplication customerApplication = new CustomerApplication();
    customerApplication.link();
    }

private void link() {
    CustomerRegister customerRegistry = new CustomerRegister();
    Controller controller = new Controller(customerRegistry, myFrame);
    myFrame.setController(controller);
    }

}
```

And lastly this is my Controller-class:

```
public class Controller {
CustomerRegister customers;
MainFrame mainFrame;

public Controller(CustomerRegister customerRegister, MainFrame mainFrame) {
    this.customers = customerRegister;
    this.mainFrame = mainFrame;
}
```

The problem is that I when I enter some information in the CustomerFormPanel and click "Add" to register; nothing happens. I think the problem is that the Controller is connected to the MainFrame and not the CustomerFormPanel. But I do not know how to parse the information from CustomerFormPanel, through CustomerPanel, through MainFrame and to the CustomerApplication.

I apologize if nothing here makes sense but it's very hard to explain this from a novice point of perspective. And I do understand if this question gets removed or the title gets changed.

**EDIT:**
Here is the addCustomer method:

```
public void addCustomer(String pNumber, String cName) {
    Customer tmpCustomer = new Customer(pNumber, cName);
    customers.addCustomer(tmpCustomer);
}
```

Comment: Where's your Controller.addCustomer method and what leads you to believe that nothing's happening?

Comment: It's in the Controller class. Right below the constructor. Well, nothing happens when I press the button which should register the customer information. I've already tried the actionlistener with a simple System.out.prinln and it works.

Comment: What are you expecting?

Comment: @Dinco Ok, maybe I used the wrong wording. Would you please include your addCustomer method.

Comment: I expect the information that the user inputs will be saved and that the Status label changes text. I can also add that when I press the button I get an error.

Answer (score 1):

To start with...

The `CustomerFormPanel` needs some way to expose the information it contains.  One solution would be to supply setters and getters that would allow the `CustomerPanel` to change/set and get the values from this component.

This ensures that you do not expose portions of the component unnecessarily (like the fields for example) and only provide access to the data that is required.

You would then need to do the same thing for the `CustomerPanel`, which would, essentially, act as proxy for `CustomerFormPanel`.  So instead of needing to expose the instance of `CustomerFormPanel` directly, you would simply provide proxy getters/setters through the `CustomerPanel`

Alternatively, you could use a [Visitor Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/visitor-pattern.html)

Basically what this means is, you would create a object which had the required setters and getters you need to build the required results and pass this into the `CustomerPanel`, the `CustomerPanel` would then set the values if has to this object and would then pass it the other forms, which would do the same, each setting the values to this object that they are managing.

Once completed, you would be able gather all the information from this object to generate the result you need, which actually describes the [build pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/builder-pattern.html)

Comment: I'm sorry but this is way over my head. Could not understand a single thing. Is it possible that you include some kind of code-example?

Answer (score 0):

If what I understood is correct, you want to access data from different classes.
Try using **static** variables. Static means that you can access them from any class in the project.

For example:

**Main.java**

```
public static String name = "Koala";
```

**PrinterClass.java**

```
System.out.println("Hi, my favourite animal is the: " + Main.name);
//output will be: Hi, my favourite animal is the Koala
```

Comment: No, especially in this context. `static` means that only one instance of the variable can exists, meaning that if you have two forms open, you will be mixing the value between, losing the correct context. `static` should be used very, very carefully and does not fit this solution...

Comment: Why is it wrong? If you want to use data from different JPanels or JFrames for example, you have to do it like this, or creating a DataBase and store all data in there.
Unless you have all the code in the same class and switch panels all time, you have to use it

Comment: The static keyword means all customer panels would be using the same controller.  What if you want to use a different controller later for only one instance of the customer panel?  Also any code anywhere in the entire project could change the static variable for all instances of the panel.  Mad programmer is definitely right, static is not the way to go.

Comment: What happens if you have more than one instance of the class that contains the `static` value?  What happens if one of these instances changes that `static` value? All the instances will share the same value, you have no context for the change as you no longer know who actually changed the value and if that value is correct.  If you suddenly have multiple `static` values, how can you guarantee the correctness of those values and if they are actually associated with each other...?

Comment: I wonder why you would want to have more than one instance of same variable, anyway... it was my fault not to say that it becomes global when using static, but I've dont programs where panels where switching and I worked this way, and was not that difficult and dangerous as you say.

Answer (score 0):

MadProgrammer has already answered your question quite completey, but to address your problem directly with an example...

It looks like you're not setting the `Controller` in your `CustomerPanel` but only in your frame.  If your frame does not need a `Controller`, just reference the `CustomerPanel` getter/setters for `Controller` (this is what MadProgrammer is referring to when he says create proxy getter/setters.

```
public class CustomerFormPanel{

    //proxy controller setter
    public void setController(Controller controller){
        customerPanel.setController(controller);
    }

    //proxy controller getter
    public Controller getController(){
        return customerPanel.getController();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not following you here. It's impossible to put these two methods within the constructor of CustomFormPanel.

Comment: Methods don't go within constructors.  They go within the CustomerFormPanel.  The `CustomerFormPanel` `CustomerPanel` `Controller` is accessed via the CustomerPanelForm's getters in setters. It in turn calls CustomerPanel's getters/setters.

Comment: I've tried it and it does not work. My frame does need a controller as specified in that class under the method "Private void link()".